# What does it mean when TsLint says "expected callSignature to have a typedef."

Tags: typescript, signature, tslint

I have a function in my code:

```
networkStop = (action: string = null) => {
    this.action[action] = false;
    this.net = false;
    this.netd = false;
}
```

I'm getting a TsLint error saying:

```
Message 4   TsLint: expected callSignature to have a typedef.
```

Can someone explain what this means?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

"Missing Type definition" See : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/typedefRule.ts for details. Basically *some* annotation (for a function because `callSignature`) is missing.

Probably the fix (specify the return type explicitly) :

```
networkStop = (action: string = null):void => {
    this.action[action] = false;
    this.net = false;
    this.netd = false;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me is putting :any after the () the same as void? In this example it returns nothing so how could I specify that? Thanks

Comment: Not its not the same. But `any` is compatible with `void` i.e. `any` can take *anything* even `void`. I would use `void` in this case ;)

Comment: For the void do I just enter :void instead of :any or is there a special syntax ?

Comment: it was useful for me

Comment: How to use this for a getter function?

Answer (score 22):

To avoid the build error.
in the **tslint.json**  file write code like:-

```
"typedef": [
  false,
  "call-signature"
],
```

This line of code in tslint.json does not make the return type of method required.

Comment: this is not the answer for this question