# What is the typedef for an async void

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

A tad related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25459136/what-does-it-mean-when-tslint-says-expected-callsignature-to-have-a-typedef), but different.

TSLint complains on this code because it needs a typedef:

```
  private async getTranslations() {
    // this.translations is a public variable used by the html
    this.translations = await this._languageService.getTranslations('Foo');
  }
```

I updated it to

```
private async getTranslations() : void { ... }
```

And this gives me the error:

> type 'void' is not a valid async function return in ES5 because it
>   does not refer to a pPromise-compatible constructor value

How can I get this right without removing the async keyword?

Comment: async function must to return Promise/Observable, so that's why you get an error here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> type 'void' is not a valid async function return in ES5 because it
>   does not refer to a pPromise-compatible constructor value

you are getting error , because when you use `async/await` then return type is going to be `Promise` wrapped object, so function return type should be `Promise<returntype>`, and in your case it will be

```
 private async getTranslations() : Promise<void> {
    // this.translations is a public variable used by the html
    this.translations = await this._languageService.getTranslations('Foo').toPromise();
  }
```

and if you are using angular then service mostly returns `observable` object , so you need to convert it in `promise` object by calling `toPromise()` function of call (if you dont put `toPromise` it will not fire request if you used httpClient in you service to get result.).

Answer (score 2):

Change return type to:

```
private async getTranslations(): Promise<void> {
  this.translations = await this._languageService.getTranslations('Foo');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return the `Observable` type

```
private async getTranslations() : Observable<any>{ ... }
```